# perf in docker doesn't show functions

Tags: docker, perf

I am trying to use perf on an application running in docker. In order to get a trace, I am running perf on the host and attaching to the application running in the container. This works fine.

However, when I try to analyze the data, it doesn't show in which functions the time is spent. It just shows the name of the .so library, but nothing else.

I have compiled the application with debug symbols (-O2 -g) but still nothing.

Do I need to set something in particular for visualizing the data in a setup where perf runs on the host but the application being traced runs on docker?

Comment: Can you update your question to include enough information for us to reproduce the problem you're asking about? That would mean some minimal code, the corresponding Dockerfile, and the specific `perf` commands you're running.

Comment: I can try to provide as much info possible, but impossible to share my dockerfile and application being traced, as its some application I am developing for my company

Comment: It is not impossible to provide *a* Dockerfile and sufficient sample code to reproduce the problem.

Comment: I know, but I first have to try to reproduce it using a minimal dockerfile that doesn't use any of my existing deployment or application code. Ill try to provide that